# How to translate choices in bot framework composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm using MS bot framework composer version 1.1.1

I'd like the user to answer a question by typing (or picking) either "yes" or "no" - but I need to support multiple languages (so in German it would be "ja" and "nein"). Of course I want to have only one bot that can handle all the languages. When the bot starts, the current language gets chosen (works). What I want to do now is that **in the active language** a question is displayed, the input yes/no is requested and depending on the input another text is shown. Not too difficult and not a very special requirement, I think.

I can get this to work adding either "Ask a question -> Confirmation" or "Ask a question -> Multi-choice" BUT only in English. In both cases I can translate the question but not the choices (suggestions) nor the validation nor the if-check evaluating the answer. What do I have to do to insert a translated text such as ${AnswerYes()} into the choices and the validation and evaluation expressions?

Inserting a translated text (similar to ${Greeting()} in the tutorials seems the correct approach to me but I cannot get it to work: Whatever I do I always get "AnswerYes does not have an evaluator, it’s not a built-in function or a custom function" although I created a translation text with that name. Any idea how to achieve that or is there another way how I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this is now being addressed in R13 of Bot Framework composer
see this issue which was only updated 7 days ago : [Composer Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2387)

R12 is currently in preview so it may be another few months before the team complete R13.